# MySql - Calculating distance in time using 2 values from 1 column (Poor design workaround)

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database

I was granted access to a legacy database in order to do some statistics work.

I've so far gotten everything I need out of it, except I am trying to calculate a distance in time, using 5 values, stored in 4 columns (ARGGGHHH)

[image]

Above is a subsection of the database.

As you can see, I have start and stop date and time.
I would like to calculate the distance in time from str_date + str_time to stp_date + stp_time

The issue I have is, the calculation should be performed differently depending on the **second value** in stp_time.

IFF second value = "DUR".... THen I can just take the first value "01:04:51" in this scenario

IFF second value = anything else. stp_time represents a **timecode** and not a duration. This must then calculate stp_time - str_time (accounting for date if not same date)

All data is 24 hour format. I have done work with conditional aggregation, but I have not figured this one out, and I have never worked with a malformed column like this before.

Any and all advice is welcome.

Thanks for reading

Comment: Not much, right now I am just doing `Case when stp_time like "%DUR%" then .... ` i get stuck becuase I don't know how to access only half the column :(  -- If I knew how to access half a column, I could probably solve the rest

Comment: Check out mysql's left() and right() functions.

Comment: Are these four values all strings?  Why do  you say three columns when you are showing us four columns?  What DBMS are you using?

Comment: All strings... because I forgot about the necessity of the Date... I updated the numbers.

Comment: @Busturdust Can you provide CREATE TABLE code for this table. It would be much easier to reproduce. (`SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename`) And a few rows (INSERTs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN RIGHT(stp_time,3)="DUR"
        THEN
            TIMEDIFF(LEFT(stp_time,8), '00:00:00')
        ELSE
            TIMEDIFF(
                STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(stp_date," ",LEFT(stp_time,8)), '%d/%b/%Y %H:%i:%s'),
                STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(str_date," ",LEFT(str_time,8)), '%d/%b/%Y %H:%i:%s')
                )
    END AS diff
FROM so33289063
```

Comment: This works, Sorry I never had a chance to do the table generation, got pulled into meetings :( ... thanks for the help, now fwiw the final query to sum for runtime per month I am using appears to also be working... Thanks again!

Comment: Next time if you provide your input data as SQL, you will get the solution much quicker. Only few people will rewrite your table from screenshot so you are losing possible solutions.

Comment: nice, @mkutyba could you give my answer a quick eye and see if you can spot my mistake?

Answer (score 1):

Try this out, you might want a where condition for the subquery
With left and right:

```
SELECT IF(dur,stp,timediff(str,stp)) FROM(
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(str_date," ",LEFT(str_time,8)), 'd%/%b/%Y %H:%i:%s') as str,
       STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(stp_date," ",LEFT(stp_time,8)), 'd%/%b/%Y %H:%i:%s') as stp,
       if(RIGHT(stp_time,3)="DUR",1,0) as dur
FROM my_table
) AS times
```

Comment: It does not work, too many arguments for STR_TO_DATE..... I took the first argument out, added a from my_table to the inner query, and it returned all null

Comment: I think @shadow guidance may be the right way to go

Comment: I missed out the concats, give that a try.

Comment: I did hyphens instead of slashes on the `STR_TO_DATE` which was wrong. One more time?

Comment: I see `d%` but can't test it now.